# How Can I see conversions Details in Google Conversion API?

Tags: google-ads-api

When I uploaded the conversion to Google ads manager account I cannot see the conversion details, I only see the last conversion date (see the image below), how can I see all conversions details.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipkTV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see conversion details. You see conversion metrics in your normal reports. Importing them doesn't show you a list, they're just associated with your campaign/ad group/keyword resources in the UI. So if you upload 1 conversion, it will be associated with all keywords with that gclid.